# El plugin maven-publish no publica en el repositorio local

Tags: kotlin, maven, gradle

Tengo el siguiente fichero de gradle 6, para un proyecto con Kotlin que utiliza el nuevo plugin maven-publish (con las versiones antiguas de gradle no era necesario esto al hacer un gradle install ya me instalaba el jar en mi maven local):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.3.61'
        validationApiVersion = '2.0.1.Final'
        cleanArchitectureVersion = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
        sl4jVersion = '1.7.25'
        testLoggerVersion = '1.6.0'
        artifactVersion = '1.0.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("com.adarshr.test-logger:com.adarshr.test-logger.gradle.plugin:${testLoggerVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'com.adarshr.test-logger'

group = 'com.talleres.paco.mako'
rootProject.archivesBaseName = 'rrhh-domain'
version = "${artifactVersion}"
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            srcDir 'src/main/kotlin'
            srcDir 'src/main/customized/kotlin'
            srcDir 'src/main/generated/kotlin'
        }
    }
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDir 'src/test/groovy'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("javax.validation:validation-api:${validationApiVersion}")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:${sl4jVersion}")
    implementation("com.talleres.paco.cleanarchitecture:commons-domain:${cleanArchitectureVersion}")
    // mandatory dependencies for using Spock
    testImplementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.13"
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4"
    // optional dependencies for using Spock
    implementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3" // only necessary if Hamcrest matchers are used
    testImplementation "net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.1"          // allows mocking of classes (in addition to interfaces)
    testImplementation "org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6"    // allows mocking of classes without default constructor (together with CGLIB)
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

testlogger {
    // pick a theme - mocha, standard, plain, mocha-parallel, standard-parallel or plain-parallel
    theme 'mocha'
    // set to false to disable detailed failure logs
    showExceptions true
    // set threshold in milliseconds to highlight slow tests
    slowThreshold 2000
    // displays a breakdown of passes, failures and skips along with total duration
    showSummary true
    // set to false to hide passed tests
    showPassed true
    // set to false to hide skipped tests
    showSkipped true
    // set to false to hide failed tests
    showFailed true
    // enable to see standard out and error streams inline with the test results
    showStandardStreams false
    // set to false to hide passed standard out and error streams
    showPassedStandardStreams true
    // set to false to hide skipped standard out and error streams
    showSkippedStandardStreams true
    // set to false to hide failed standard out and error streams
    showFailedStandardStreams true
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.3"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el comando (con gradle 6):
**gradle publishToMavenLocal**

Veo que se ha generado el jar en la ruta (**/build/libs)**.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La salida que da en la línea de comando es:

```
❯ gradle publishToMavenLocal
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
6 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

Pero no se ha copiado en mi repositorio local de maven.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una alternativa sería subir el jar a mano con el comando maven para instalarlo en mi repositorio local. Pero esto antes funcionaba en gradle sin tener que añadir un plugin específico ni especificar más cosas.
¿Alguna idea al respecto?.
Gracias anticipadas y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tema está en que tengo la consola WSL de Windows 10. Tengo un maven dentro del Ubuntu de la WSL y otro maven en Windows 10. Estaba mirando el de windows 10 por eso no se veía.